# Download the images from remote with a list from local

Tags: bash, ubuntu, shell

I have a list of images in a `images.txt` file (local), which contains relative image paths as:

```
a/b/abc.jpg
a/b/abcd.jpg
1/2/123.jpg
1/2/1234.jpg
...
```

I want to download only those images from remote preserving the folder structure.
I tried to use the command as

```
cd /path/to/my/project
scp -rv user@remote-host:/var/www/domain.com/public_html/assets/media/{"$(cat images.txt | tr '\n' ',' | sed 's/,$//')"} ./assets/media
```

But it downloaded all the images under `./assets/media` directory directly instead of respective folders (for ex: `a/b`, `1/2`, etc.).

How to modify the command? may be using `rsync` or `scp`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would either use `rsync` or a loop with `scp`, depending on what was available:

```
while IFS= read -r file
do
    mkdir -p "assets/media/${file%/*}"
    scp -pv user@remote-host:"/var/www/domain.com/public_html/assets/media/$file" assets/media
done <images.txt
```

The problem with using just `scp` is that directories corresponding to the source paths are not automatically created, so we have to create them explicitly.

My go-to tool would more likely be `rsync`, which can handle all this in a single command

```
rsync -avR --files-from images.txt user@remote-host:/var/www/domain.com/public_html/assets/media/ assets/media
```

Here the "magic" is the `-R` flag, which tells `rsync` to treat the source paths listed in `images.txt` as relative not only to the source but also to the destination. So `/var/www/domain.com/public_html/assets/media/a/b/abc.jpg` will be copied from the remote system to `assets/media/a/b/abc.jpg` locally.

---

As an afterthought, a comment has asked how a list of filenames could be handled if they were in an array. Here is what I'd probably do

```
printf "%s\0" "${files[@]}" |
    rsync -avR --files-from - --from0 user@remote-host:/var/www/domain.com/public_html/assets/media/ assets/media
```

Comment: `rysnc` command looks cool. Will give a try and update you.

Comment: `--files-from <filename>` works. But wondering if we can read the filename from an array?

Comment: Your question showed them in a file. An array is a different thing altogether (having a think about how I'd do it)